# How can I iterate over each item and render on the screen?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, foreach

I've been trying to iterate over each item for forecast data and can't figure out where the outputs are coming from.. I'm only trying to iterate over temperature, pressure, place name, humidity, wind speed and feels like..

Json

```
{
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0,
  "cnt": 40,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1641124800,
      "main": {
        "temp": 11.74,
        "feels_like": 11.08,
        "temp_min": 11.74,
        "temp_max": 12,
        "pressure": 1012,
        "sea_level": 1012,
        "grnd_level": 1008,
        "humidity": 81,
        "temp_kf": -0.26
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 803,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "broken clouds",
          "icon": "04d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 75
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 5.3,
        "deg": 229,
        "gust": 11.75
      },
      "visibility": 10000,
      "pop": 0,
      "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2022-01-02 12:00:00"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1641135600,
      "main": {
        "temp": 11.86,
        "feels_like": 11.11,
        "temp_min": 11.86,
        "temp_max": 12.09,
        "pressure": 1011,
        "sea_level": 1011,
        "grnd_level": 1006,
        "humidity": 77,
        "temp_kf": -0.23
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 500,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "light rain",
          "icon": "10d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 83
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 6.45,
        "deg": 223,
        "gust": 15.9
      },
      "visibility": 10000,
      "pop": 0.7,
      "rain": {
        "3h": 0.6
      },
      "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2022-01-02 15:00:00"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1641146400,
      "main": {
        "temp": 11.29,
        "feels_like": 10.43,
        "temp_min": 11.06,
        "temp_max": 11.29,
        "pressure": 1011,
        "sea_level": 1011,
        "grnd_level": 1007,
        "humidity": 75,
        "temp_kf": 0.23
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 500,
          "main": "Rain",
          "description": "light rain",
          "icon": "10n"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 92
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 6.1,
        "deg": 250,
        "gust": 13.97
      },
      "visibility": 10000,
      "pop": 0.94,
      "rain": {
        "3h": 1.01
      },
      "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2022-01-02 18:00:00"
    },
    {
      "dt": 1641157200,
      "main": {
        "temp": 9.54,
        "feels_like": 6.37,
        "temp_min": 9.54,
        "temp_max": 9.54,
        "pressure": 1012,
        "sea_level": 1012,
        "grnd_level": 1009,
        "humidity": 76,
        "temp_kf": 0
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 802,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "scattered clouds",
          "icon": "03n"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 36
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 6.93,
        "deg": 244,
        "gust": 14.72
      },
      "visibility": 10000,
      "pop": 0,
      "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2022-01-02 21:00:00"
    },
{
      "dt": 1641546000,
      "main": {
        "temp": 3.96,
        "feels_like": 0.41,
        "temp_min": 3.96,
        "temp_max": 3.96,
        "pressure": 1010,
        "sea_level": 1010,
        "grnd_level": 1007,
        "humidity": 82,
        "temp_kf": 0
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 804,
          "main": "Clouds",
          "description": "overcast clouds",
          "icon": "04d"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 100
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 4.29,
        "deg": 239,
        "gust": 11.29
      },
      "visibility": 10000,
      "pop": 0.02,
      "sys": {
        "pod": "d"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2022-01-07 09:00:00"
    }
  ],
  "city": {
    "id": 2643743,
    "name": "London",
    "coord": {
      "lat": 51.5085,
      "lon": -0.1257
    },
    "country": "GB",
    "population": 1000000,
    "timezone": 0,
    "sunrise": 1641110761,
    "sunset": 1641139355
  }
}
```

in forecast.dart

```
import 'package:forecast/models/weather_data.dart';

class ForecastData {
  final List list;

  ForecastData({required this.list});

  factory ForecastData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['list']?.map((e) => e)?.toList(growable: true) ?? [];
    List weatherData = [];
    list.forEach((e) {
      WeatherData w = WeatherData(
          placeName: json['city']['name'],
          temperature: e['main']['temp'],
          feels_like: e['main']["feels_like"],
          pressure: e['main']['pressure'],
          humidity: e['main']['humidity'],
          wind_speed: e['wind']['speed']);

      weatherData.add(w);
      print(weatherData.toList());
    });

    return ForecastData(list: weatherData);
  }
}
```

weatherdata.dart

```
class WeatherData {
  String? placeName;
  num? temperature;
  num? feels_like;
  num? pressure;
  num? humidity;
  num? wind_speed;

  WeatherData({
    this.placeName,
    this.temperature,
    this.feels_like,
    this.pressure,
    this.humidity,
    this.wind_speed,
  });
  @override
  String toString() =>
      '${placeName ?? 'unknown'}${feels_like ?? 'unknown'}${temperature ?? 'unknown'}${pressure ?? 'unknown'}${humidity ?? 'unknown'}${wind_speed ?? 'unknown'}';

  WeatherData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    placeName = json['city']['name'];
    temperature = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
    feels_like = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
    pressure = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
    humidity = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
    wind_speed = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
  }
}
```

output

```
I/flutter (25471): [London11.0811.741012815.3]
I/flutter (25471): [London11.0811.741012815.3, London11.1111.861011776.45]
I/flutter (25471): [London11.0811.741012815.3, London11.1111.861011776.45, London10.4311.291011756.1]
I/flutter (25471): [London11.0811.741012815.3, London11.1111.861011776.45, London10.4311.291011756.1, London6.379.541012766.93]
I/flutter (25471): [London11.0811.741012815.3, London11.1111.861011776.45, London10.4311.291011756.1, London6.379.541012766.93, London6.229.481013757.18]
I/flutter (25471): [London11.0811.741012815.3, London11.1111.861011776.45, London10.4311.291011756.1, London6.379.541012766.93, London6.229.481013757.18, London6.039.051013796.02]
I/flutter (25471): [London11.0811.741012815.3, London11.1111.861011776.45, London10.4311.291011756.1, London6.379.541012766.93, London6.229.481013757.18, London6.039.051013796.02, London5.698.681012795.66]
```

I can't figure out where the problem is..why is my output iterating like this? I just need to iterate over each item and print out each item each time please help!

Answer (score 1):

in `forecast.dart`, You are printing the whole `weatherData` list in the iterator `list.forEach`.

Try changing ,

```dart
print(weatherData.toList());
```

to,

```dart
print(w);
```

And put some spaces in your `toString`

```
${placeName ?? 'unknown'} ${feels_like ?? 'unknown'} ${te...
```

so that you can see where one number ends and the next starts.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed the code to see each value like ```print(w.temperature)``` ,seems like working but then when I run```print(w);```the values are different from when I run each variable like ```print(w.temperature);```also w doesn't contain 6 values.. but output is the following: I/flutter (31970): London3.155.481015852.91
I/flutter (31970): London1.445.221015845.37
I/flutter (31970): London1.924.631016833.2
I/flutter (31970): London3.636.31016693.69

Comment: I'm just trying to iterate over each item of temperature, pressure, place name, humidity, wind speed and feels like and add them to the empty list weatherData and return it so I can render it on the screen..how can I do this?

Answer (score -1):

I think that you shoul lose the map and review the fromJson parameters...

```js
  WeatherData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    placeName = json['city']['name'];
    temperature = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
    feels_like = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
    pressure = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
    humidity = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
    wind_speed = json['list'][0]['main']['temp'];
  }
```

Comment: I checked them again and changed the code print(w.temperature) in forecast.dart to see if correct values are printed and it did. then when I run print(w) the values are not what I expected.. output is the following: I/flutter (31970): London3.155.481015852.91
I/flutter (31970): London1.445.221015845.37
I/flutter (31970): London1.924.631016833.2
I/flutter (31970): London3.636.31016693.69